# Is there a limit to how many metamagic feats can be put on a spell if you are using the spell point system?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, spellcasting, metamagic

In my current campaign I'm playing a Kobold sorcerer using the spell point system and I have recently gained a few metamagic feats and this question popped into my head.

When using spell points is there a limit to how many metamagic feats that you can add to a single spell? Because when you use spell slots with metamagic feats you can't go over a 9th level spell slot with the feats but from what I have seen there is no limit to how many spell points can be used to cast a spell.

So for this question lets say hypothetically I am somehow able to use every single metamagic feat in the base game in some form. Would I be able to add all of the compatible feats to the spell at once, if I had enough spell points to cast it or is there a hard cap to the number of metamagic feats I can add to a spell?

Comment: Does the campaign use the spell point system described [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spell-points-magic-system/)? If not, the question needs a link to or a description of the spell point system that's used in the campiagn.

Answer (score 2):

### Same limitations as the standard rules

From [the SRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spell-points-magic-system/)

> Like standard spellcasters, spell-point spellcasters cannot use metamagic feats to boost a spell’s effective level to be higher than the highest-level spell the character can cast.

So if you are a 17th level Wizard with lvl 9 slots, the maximum level of your spell post-metamagic is 9. From that you can use the same tricks as non-spell-point spellcasters to reduce the cost of some metamagics but in the end you will have the exact same limitation.

Comment: If it turns out that the campaign the asker's in uses the standard *Pathfinder* spell points variant, you may want to add this from the same page: "A spellcaster can apply multiple metamagic feats to a single spell. Changes to its level are cumulative. You can’t apply the same metamagic feat more than once to a single spell."